Is there a way to validate Python objects against a pyarrow schema?
I have a pyarrow Schema defined and a list of native Python dictionaries. I can use
pyarrow.Table.from_pylist(list_of_python_objects, schema=SCHEMA)

and that will create a table matching the schema. However, I'd like to be able to validate the Python objects against the pyarrow schema, similarly to how pyarrow.json.ParseOptions.unexpected_field_behavior = "error" will raise an exception if the object has fields in it that aren't in the provided schema.
Right now, the implementation of from_pylist iterates over the schema by field name and has no logic to detect and raise an exception if extra keys are in the input objects.

I can't think of a way using pyarrow.Table.
However since you are talking about json, if you can get your data formatted in json lines (jsonl), you can do this sort of validation with pyarrow.json:
{"field_1": 1, "field_2": "foo"}
{"field_1": 1, "field_2": "foo", "field_3": 123.0}

import pyarrow.json

table = pyarrow.json.read_json(
    "good.jsonl",
    parse_options=pa.json.ParseOptions(
        explicit_schema=SCHEMA, unexpected_field_behavior="error"
    ),
)


